# How to call jQuery with button

Tags: html, jquery, css, button

I am editing a website that is automated with java, I am creating a menu to hide few divs that are repated with same id and same class. I managed to do it already with jQuery with this:

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[id]').each(function () {
            var ids = $('[id=catalog_container' + this.id + ']');
            if (ids.length > 1 && ids[0] == this) {
                $(ids[0]).remove();
            }
        });
    });
```

I need to do it in another way, but I don't know how to do it. I want to do it with button.
`<li><a><button onclick="myFunction()">1 Catalog</button></a></li>`  
Something like that, when I press that button, to remove first duplicated id, when I press another button to remove second duplicated ID, and so on.
Help me please.
I'd like to know how to do it like this too: not to load script automatically as it does, I want to know how to call it.

Comment: It sounds like you need a [`click()` event handler](https://api.jquery.com/click). However, your references to 'duplicated ids' is a little concerning - there should never be duplicate `id` attributes in the DOM. If that is happening in your case, edit the HTML to remove them. Don't use JS as a crutch to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution, I will post it for anyone to see it, and give feedback if you want!

```
<!-- Hide second id -->
         $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#Catalog").click(function () {
            $('[id]').each(function () {
                var ids = $('[id=' + this.id + ']');
                if (ids.length > 1 && ids[0] == this) {
                    $(ids[1]).hide(); 
                    $(ids[0]).show(); 
                } 
                });
            });
        });

         $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#Catalog2").click(function () {
            $('[id]').each(function () {
                var ids = $('[id=' + this.id + ']');
                if (ids.length > 1 && ids[0] == this) {
                    $(ids[0]).hide(); 
                    $(ids[1]).show(); 
                } 
                });
            });
        });

<!-- Hide First ID -->

         $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#Catalog").click(function () {
            $('[class]').each(function () {
                var ids = $('[class=category-title' + this.id + ']');
                if (ids.length > 1 && ids[0] == this) {
                    $(ids[1]).hide(); 
                    $(ids[0]).show(); 
                } 
                });
            });
        });

         $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#Catalog2").click(function () {
            $('[class]').each(function () {
                var ids = $('[class=category-title' + this.id + ']');
                if (ids.length > 1 && ids[0] == this) {
                    $(ids[0]).hide(); 
                    $(ids[1]).show(); 
                } 
                });
            });
        });
```

```
         <ul>
             <li><a><button style="color:black;" id="Catalog">1 Catalog</button></a></li>
             <li><a><button style="color:black;" id="Catalog2">2 Catalog</button></a></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Please revise your answer to describe what you changed, either as an introduction or as inline comments. Don't make readers do a line-by-line comparison to see the changes.

Comment: Also, you don't need separate `document.ready` blocks for each function. Put them all in one.

Comment: You've assigned two event handlers to each of your two buttons. Won't they conflict?